# Docker - install php-memcached extension not working?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have been trying to install memcached in my php-5.6 container, however I am unable to get it working, as i don't see memcached extension in phpinfo() and plus for some reason it's complaining about that it can't find the memcache.so in the code.

there is my docker-file for php build

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd     

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli mbstring pdo_mysql 

# Download and Installing php libraries 
RUN apt-get install -y memcached
RUN apt-get -y install php-pear php5-dev php5-memcached geoip-bin geoip-database libgeoip-dev php5-geoip

# Download and Installing php libraries 
RUN pecl install geoip

# Download and Installing git and vim 
RUN apt-get -y install git gcc  

RUN pwd
RUN git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git 
WORKDIR /var/www/html/cphalcon/build
RUN ./install

EXPOSE 9000
EXPOSE 11211

COPY ./php-fpm.d/www.conf /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
COPY ./php.ini  /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini 
COPY ./php-fpm.conf /etc/php-fpm.conf
COPY ./phalcon.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/phalcon.ini
COPY ./geoip.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/geoip.ini
COPY ./memcached.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/memcached.ini
```

And my docker compose file is

```
nginx:
    build: ./.config/etc/nginx/
    ports:
        - 7000:80
    links:
        - php
        - memcached:memcached            
    volumes_from:
        - app

memcached:
  image: memcached:latest   

php:
    build: ./.config/etc/php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
        - memcached:memcached            
    volumes_from:
        - app

app:
    image: php:5.6-fpm
    #image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs
    command: "true"
```

The error i am getting on the code is

**[36;1mnginx_1      | [0mPHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'memcache' not found in Unknown on line 0" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: www.example.dev, request: "GET /search HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.17.0.5:9000", host: "192.168.99.100:7000"**

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `php` images ship a custom-compiled PHP, but are based on a Debian Jessie image (and use Debian's repositories). With `apt-get install php5-memcached`, you install the `memcached` extension for the distribution's PHP package (which is installed along the way).

You need to install the `memcached` extension via PECL (and its build dependencies via APT):

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y libz-dev libmemcached-dev && \
    pecl install memcached && \
    docker-php-ext-enable memcached
```